Breakdown of the Fermi gas model for the nucleus
One of the predictions of the Fermi gas model for the nucleus is that the most energetically favorable situation for a nucleus is to have $N=Z$, an equal number of protons and neutrons. Observing the Segrè chart, this is true for the lighter nuclei. However, heavier nuclei tend to have $N>Z$.
If we consider the well known relationship between radius and mass number, $R\sim A^{1/3}$, it's easy to notice that $V\sim A$. Then the average nucleon density $\rho=A/V$ should remain approximately constant for most nuclei (this seems to be true, at least as far as I know).
This means that a $^4\mathrm{He}$ nucleus shouldn't be much less dense than a $^{206}\mathrm{Pb}$ nucleus. Under that assumption, it seems reasonable to believe that an independent particle model like the Fermi gas model should apply in both cases, given that the fermions are under similar conditions. However, $N=Z$ is only a stable situation for one of them.
My question is, given that the average nucleon density seems to be more or less constant for all nuclei, why does the Fermi gas model not yield correct results for heavier nuclei, when it comes to their stability?

Didn't the textbooks cover this? There is at least Coulomb repulsion between protons that do not exist between neutrons, and that tips highly charged nuclei towards having more neutrons to spread out the electric charge and hold the nucleons together.

It's worth reading up on the semi-empirical mass formula, which contains more physics than assuming the nucleons are independent, and which captures at least some of the scaling of $N/Z$ with $A$ for larger nuclei.

A Fermi gas consists of non-interacting particles. However, the protons in the nucleus have a mutual repulsion and this breaks the equivalence between neutron and proton energy levels and leads to favouring stable nuclei with $N>Z$ as the number of nucleons increases.
The effect grows with increasing $Z$ because the Coulomb repulsion is proportional to $Z^2$.
